# Nesting components in Angular 12 - issue with 'Scope'

Tags: angular, components

just trying to get my head around Angular12 after years on AngularJS and am having what I hope is a simple to fix problem: I know that Scope is no longer but it appears that the component is rendering data from a different scope.

I have a component that gets some results from a service and displays them on the page.

> `<app-search-component>`
> This has a method called doSearch(xxxx) that populates this.items and then renders the result.

If I route to that component directly it all works perfectly.

What I am trying to active is to use that componet in a similar way to a directive in angular JS

I have tried passing the component via the constructor &  tried creating a new component within my component but I cannot get the child component to refresh its view.

It seems that when debugging the child component has a different 'scope' to the version on my template.

Template example My Parent Component

```
  <form [formGroup] ="searchForm" class="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field class="search-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput value="" formControlName="name">
      </mat-form-field>
    
      <mat-form-field class="search-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="email">
       
      </mat-form-field> 
      <mat-form-field class="search-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Postcode</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="postcode">
       
      </mat-form-field>
    
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type = "submit">Search</button>
</form> 
<app-search-component>
```

My parent component contains a call to the search method as follows:

Constructor:

```
this.searchComp= new MySearchComponent(_myService, _zone);
```

On Submit

```
 this.searchComp.doSearch(this.searchText);
```

Comment: I guess you create a component in you view AND in the constructor. You should not create an instance in constructor. If you need to access public methods defined on the component use ViewChield decorator in you case. Or, what i this is the better approach use an Input on the search component and pass "searchText" the normal way to the component. Information about view chield: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild and information about Input: https://angular.io/api/core/Input in the ngOnChanges Method you could call your method "doSearch"

Comment: Thanks @Thomas - literally just about to update my own question. Finding Angular 12 a mix of pain and pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options here. you can have the search be done via a service or you can use viewchild for this. to make the code seem more like you already have you can do something like this in your parent component

```
@ViewChild(MySearchComponent)
searchComp : MySearchComponent
```

the template will create the component for you so remove the new MySearchComponent from your constructor

Comment: Thanks @henrik - I was literally just about to update this - I found viewchild :-) - seems easy once you know what to look for.